# jQuery - add pixels to height according to screen width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to do this with jQuery.

Let's say that I have simple div element in HTML like that:

```
<div class="grow"></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
body, html {
width: 100%; 
height:100%;
min-height:100%
}

.grow {
height:20px; 
width:100%;
}
```

I need to write script where DIV `grow` will be growing according to the screen resolution. Starting from 90px's.

Sth like this:

For **90px** screen wide DIV height will be - **20px**
For **130px** screen wide DIV height will be - **30px**

**so for any 4px's width height will grow 1px.**

I tried lots of solutions but without any luck. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: And you definitely want it with the screen resolution, not responsive with the size of the browser window?

Comment: If it will be growing anytime for each 4px width 1px height it will be working so I think it will be enough for me, but with pleasure I will hear your idea :)

Comment: 90/4 = 22 (rounded) not 20 so I don't get it

Comment: Width below 90px don't bother me. I only need this to work starting from 90 px's width to infinity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here you go [http://jsfiddle.net/6KfHy/1/]

```
var baseWidth = 90;
var stepWidth = 4;
var baseHeight = 20;
var growHeightPerStep = 1;

function changeHeight() {
    var windowW = $(window).width();
    var diffWidth = windowW - baseWidth;
    var diffHeight = parseInt(diffWidth / 4, 10);

    $('.grow').css('height', baseHeight + diffHeight + 'px');
}

changeHeight();

$(window).resize(function() {
    changeHeight();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    var bodyheight = $(document).height();
    var divHeight = (bodyheight-10)/2;
    $('.grow').css("height", divHeight+"px");;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var width = (+$(window).width());
var divHeight = (width-10)/2;
$(".grow").height(divHeight);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var $grow = $('.grow'),
    $window = $(window);
$(window)
    .resize(function () {
        var windowWidth = $window.width();
        if (windowWidth > 90) {
            $grow.height(~~ (windowWidth / 4));
        }
    })
    .resize();
```

Trigger it the first time on dom ready.

http://jsfiddle.net/techunter/Xug5A/

remark careful with `.grow` margins and paddings :)